# How background image not worked in my chrome nor firefox

Tags: html, css

I am making a html page in html. I am integrated them in aspx page and trying to run them vs/webmatrix.

it's not working.
when I check the image location and copy paste them in browser it's work but in real it's not show. Only Ie9 show me this.

```
<div class="ads-head-wrap">
                        <h2>Favorite Stores</h2>
                    </div>

.ads-head-wrap {
background: url("../images/ads-head.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
width: 233px;
height: 51px;
}
```

Do someone know what exactly goes wrong in my case.

---

update :-

I found a plugin installed on firefox and chrome that block the image because they thing it's advertisement.

Comment: In firebug, what happens when you hover over the URL of the background image? Does it show or says failed to load?

Comment: firebug and chrome dev tool both show me the image.

Comment: This is not your literal code, though, is it? Can you show the full code with `<style>` tags and everything?

Comment: Its most probably because of error in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your image file, **ads** may be a sensitive word for some ad-block plugins and firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DOM inspector on the browsers where it doesn't work, turn off ALL other styles that affect "ads-head-wrap". This may indicated where your problem is. I suspect there is another rule affecting this.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is no issue in code. Possibly background image source path is not correct.   Please check that or please provide link of that page so we can check that and identify the issue.

thanks,

Comment: I am not sure what exactly happen. i have check that image is failed to call from page but I can call them in browser directly. I found a amazing thing that IE9 work fine here.

Comment: The path is correct, he already said it works in IE9 and when he pastes the location in the browser's address bar.